# nesting loop with forEachSeries and whilst together

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am using `forEachSeries` and `whilst` together as follows:

```
async.forEachSeries(BJRegion, function (region, key, callback) {
  var count = 0;

  async.whilst(
    function () { return count < 10; },
    function (cb) {
      // sth...
    },
    function (err, count) {             
      console.log(err, count);                              
    }
  ); // whilst
}); // forEachSeries
```

However, it seems that when the first while loop is done, the outer `forEach` does not go to the next element. Without `whilst`, `forEach` iterates over every element in the `BJRegion` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking the outer callback when `async.whilst` exits. You need something like

```
async.forEachSeries(..., function(item, next) {
  async.whilst(
    function() { ... },
    function(callback) {
      // do some work
      // ...

      // continue to the next "whilst" iteration
      callback();
    },
    function(err) {
      // "whilst" is finished!
      // continue to the next "forEachSeries" iteration
      next();
    }
  )
});
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pyz5q474/2/).